# kafka spout is not emitting data

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to integrate Kafka with storm.I am using Kafka Spout for retrieving data from the Kafka topics and feeding it to the storm bolts for further processing.I am able to submit the topology successfully but the spout is not emitting any data.It does not throws any errors as well. I am very new to Kafka and Storm.So, I am not able to get the reason behind this problem.Please suggests the modifications.Thanks in Advance !!

[image: Screen Shot of Storm UI after submitting the topology]

**My Topology :**

```
public class TopologyMain {

 private static final String SENTENCE_SPOUT_ID = "kafka-sentence-spout";


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException {
    int numSpoutExecutors = 1;


    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    builder.setSpout(SENTENCE_SPOUT_ID, buildKafkaSentenceSpout(), numSpoutExecutors);
    builder.setBolt("word-normalizer", new WordNormalizer())
        .shuffleGrouping(SENTENCE_SPOUT_ID);
    builder.setBolt("word-counter", new WordCounter(),2)
        .shuffleGrouping("word-normalizer");

    //Configuration
    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setDebug(false);
    //Topology run
    conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 1);
    conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_HOST, "192.168.1.229");
    conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_THRIFT_PORT, 6627);
    System.setProperty("storm.jar", "/home/ubuntu/st/stIn/target/storm-wc.jar");
    StormSubmitter.submitTopology("Count-Word-Topology", conf,builder.createTopology());

}



 private static KafkaSpout buildKafkaSentenceSpout() {
      BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts("localhost:2181");
      SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, "test", "/acking-kafka-sentence-spout", "acking-sentence-spout");
      spoutConfig.forceFromStart = true;
      spoutConfig.startOffsetTime = kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime();
      return new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);
    }
 }
```

Comment: are you able to consume topic using the console script? is this topology working in local ? can u run any sample topology from the [storm-starter](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter) in your cluster?

Comment: Ya, I am able to consume topics using the console-script.And the topology is working fine in local.Also, I able to run different storm topology on cluster where spout is a text file.

Comment: if your zookeeper is running in the same ip as `Config.NIMBUS_HOST` then please try chaning localhost:2181 to <mc_ip>:2181 and see if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explicitly copied all the jars which where there in the Maven dependency of my project to the storm library and things are working fine.Also i copied the storm jar(jar used for submitting the topology) to the storm/lib.

Comment: i'm new and facing the same problem, do you mean by  jars which where there in the Maven dependency of my project , jars which i submitted it ?

Comment: @user3188912 copy all the jars which are present in the maven dependency of your project to the storm lib..Also copy the storm topology jar there.and set this property . `System.setProperty("storm.jar", "location of the topology jar");`

Comment: check on which port your kafka spout is running..then check the corresponding worker log..that will give you the exact reason for the failing of your spout.

Comment: i'm using storm-0.8.2 not kafka but problem same, is that different or not ?

Comment: It is always better to use the new stable binaries..I suggest you to use storm 0.9.4 onwards..as many common bugs are fixed in it..it doesn't matter if you are using kafka or not..you need to have all the jars present in the storm lib along with the topology jar to run the code..If you don't want to do it..then create a shaded jar or fat jar and submit topology using that.

Comment: Really Thanks for replying i'll try it now

Comment: sorry for late reply , i have problem in my laptop , what is the version you using in ubuntu ? and if you don't have any problem would you like to send me your email ?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.0.4.I don't think your problem is related to Ubuntu version.Post your questions under `storm` tag.I can surely help you out and also other people can take benefits from our discussions.